# Rails 5 in applicationHelper an helper is visible, another not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning rails.
I'm build a simple test application, with a simple authentication scheme.
I'm using a user.role field to group the users.
In my Application Helper i have:

```
module ApplicationHelper
def current_user
  if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  else
    @current_user = nil
  end
end

def user_identity
  current_user.role if current_user
end
end
```

Now, in my app, i can use current_user in all controllers as expected, but instead user_identity is not visible.

why?

Answer (score 1):

The application_helper is used mainly to access methods in views - I don't believe it's available in a controller.

The reason your 'current_user' method appears to work is that I'm assuming you're using Devise - when you call 'current_user' it is using the Engine's method rather than your own.

To solve this, write out a new module:

```
module MyHelper
  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    else
      @current_user = nil
    end
  end

  def user_identity
    current_user.role if current_user
  end
end
```

And in the controller you're using:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyHelper

  bla bla bla...
end
```

Any methods defined in MyHelper will now be available in MyController, as we've included the module in the controller

Comment: The thinking on this one is backwards as the helpers don't have access to the session anyway, which tells you this code belongs in the controllers. If you still need it in the view you can use the built in AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods#helper_method in the controllers to expose it for the views. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method

Comment: @engineerDave you are wrong about about helpers not being able to access the session. They are mixed into the view context and the view context proxies everything to the controller. You are right however in that this code does not belong in a helper.

Answer (score 1):

Helper modules are mixed into the view context (the implicit *self* in your views) - not controllers.

So you can call it from the controller with:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def index
    view_context.user_identity
  end
end
```

Or you can include the helper with the `helper` method:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  helper :my_helper
  def index
    user_identity
  end
end
```

But if you're writing a set of authentication methods I wouldn't use a helper in the first place. Helpers are supposed to be aids for the view.

Instead I would create a concern (also a module) and include it in ApplicationController:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/authenticable.rb
module Authenticable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= session[:user_id] ? User.find(session[:user_id]) : nil
  end 

  def user_identity
    current_user.try(:role)
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Authenticable
end
```

Since the view can access any of the controllers methods this adds the methods to both contexts.

Comment: Something don't run. A part the simple correction extend instead of extends, if i build the Authenticable as class it give me error when i include it in application controller, instead, if i build the Authenticable as a Module, it don't simply run in the views. Can you help me? Your approach is very interesting and it will be very useful in my rails learning.

Comment: Oops, there where two typos (extends instead of extend, and declaring a class instead of a module). Try it again.

Comment: I've corrected the typos, using also module instead of class. But, again, i cannot use current_user in the views.

Comment: Ok. Found the problem. @max you made another error in your code. It need to add: included do helper_method :current_user in the code. Without that the views cannot access at the method